# Python plotly scatter_geo modify hover data

Tags: python, hover, plotly, scatter

I want to modify hover data and leave ther for e.g. only `bins` data.
I made following code, but `hover_data` parameter didn't work. What is the way to modify haver data?

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

rows=[['501-600','15','122.58333','45.36667'],
      ['till 500','4','12.5','27.5'],
      ['more 1001','41','-115.53333','38.08'],
      ]

colmns=['bins','data','longitude','latitude']
df=pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=colmns)
df = df.astype({"data": int})

fig=px.scatter_geo(df,lon='longitude', lat='latitude',
                      color='bins',
                      opacity=0.5,
                      size='data',
                      projection="natural earth", hover_data=(['bins']))

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(lon=df["longitude"],
              lat=df["latitude"],
              text=df["data"],
              textposition="middle center",
              mode='text',
              showlegend=False))
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can mention as below for hover_data argument of scatter_geo.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

rows=[['501-600','15','122.58333','45.36667'],
      ['till 500','4','12.5','27.5'],
      ['more 1001','41','-115.53333','38.08'],
      ]

colmns=['bins','data','longitude','latitude']
df=pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=colmns)
df = df.astype({"data": int})

fig=px.scatter_geo(df,lon='longitude', lat='latitude',
                      color='bins',
                      opacity=0.5,
                      size='data',
                      projection="natural earth", hover_data={'longitude':False,'latitude':False,'data':False})

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(lon=df["longitude"],
              lat=df["latitude"],
              text=df["data"],
              textposition="middle center",
              mode='text',
              showlegend=False))


fig.show()
```

Setting the columns name as False in hover_data will remove that column name from hover_data. 
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: now in it's output: `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Comment: I ran your whole program with changes in hover_data. It gave correct output. Did u change the columns in data frame?

Comment: Hi, I updated my comment with entire program that gave expected output for me.

Comment: It gave me still the same output. Maybe coz of version of libs?

Comment: seems like this should work, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Hover Template:** A [hover template](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#customizing-hover-text-with-a-hovertemplate) might work well in this situation:

```py
fig=px.scatter_geo(df,lon='longitude', lat='latitude',
                      #color='bins',
                      opacity=0.5,
                      size='data',
                      projection="natural earth")

fig.update_traces(customdata=df.bins)
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='Bins: %{customdata}<extra></extra>')
```

See [here](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#adding-other-data-to-the-hover-with-customdata-and-a-hovertemplate) and [here](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scattergeo.html) about using `customdata` in a hover template.

> **customdata** – Assigns extra data each datum. This may be useful when
>   listening to hover, click and selection events. Note that, “scatter”
>   traces also appends customdata items in the markers DOM elements

**Update**: using the `color` option in `px.scatter_geo` will group the resulting plot's data such that the `customdata` no longer aligns with the underlining plot data.  This is usually the point I abandon plotly express and use plotly go.

Comment: Thx, but if I do like you advised then in viz I just see word `bins` without any data itself, I also tried to apply info from your link like that:
`fig.update_traces(hovertemplate ='%{bins}')`
But in this case I got: `%{bins}`
What do you think?

Comment: you are correct, it only appeared to work (at least from me) because the "bins" data was showing up in the `<extra>` hover field.  Adding `customdata` appears to help (see update above), BUT the `color` option will break it.  I'll continue to look at this and let you know if I come up with anything better.

Comment: also, you might find using `go.Scattergeo` inplace of `px.scatter_geo` easier to work with.

Comment: Seems that "bins" data showing within `customdata`. Interesting by what logic? And what if I wat to add several data fields to show there? Yet again, I need to save legeng and colors which are there now

Comment: added some more info above, but in short, yes you can add multiple fields to `customdata`.  I'm still investigating the color part.

Comment: seems somehow it should be possible to add through `customdata` several data in a way of - `customdata[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Using the accepted answer, I found the following error (similar to in @Asha Ramprasad's comments):

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

as well, for the following:

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 13:42:34) 
>>> import plotly
>>> plotly.__version__
'4.4.1'
```

**I removed the error by passing a list of the dataframe columns I wanted, instead of a dictionary:**

```
hover_data = [df["whatever I want displayed"],df["other thing to display"]]
```

This plotly behavior seems like a bug to me. Note that this doesn't allow removing columns, only adding.